# I want to get export from datagridview to text file but I get error

Tags: c#, datagridview, export-to-text

I want to get export from datagridview to text file but i get following `error` :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' 
occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Request for the permission of type
'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

This is my `code` :

```
const string path = @"d:\export.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Create(path);
}
TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\export.txt");

int rowcount = dgvSum.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
{
    sw.WriteLine(dgvSum.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}
sw.Close();


MessageBox.Show(@"Text file was created.");
```

this is my report for try-catch :
[this is my report for try-catch:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfyrv.jpg)

[this is report after changeing path and filename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOKvf.jpg)

This id exact `code` after some edit :

```
try
{
    const string path = @"c:\123\123.txt";

    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path, 
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream))

    {
        int rowcount = dgvSum.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(dgvSum.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    MessageBox.Show(@"Text file was created.");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
    //Console.WriteLine(exception);
}
```

Comment: If you wrap your code in a `try-catch` block you should see that the problem is related to permissions on the file.

Comment: so how can i fix this?

Comment: You need to check that you have permissions to write to the D: drive.

Comment: how can i fix that permission?

Comment: Basic ntfs permission management http://www.wikihow.com/Change-File-Permissions-on-Windows-7

Comment: it is getting mr crazy. what can i do for export???!!!!!!

Comment: Try creating the file `export.txt` manually and putting it in `D:`. The code I provided definitely works, so the issue appears to be something local to your machine.

Comment: i try it with another system and another OS but i gave same error

Comment: Does that pc have a D: drive?

Comment: yes it have. i try with another drive and another file name but it dodnt work

Comment: Ok, please provide the exact code that you're running.

Comment: i edit frist post and out exact cod that i run at the end of it

Comment: What exception are you getting now? The code runs fine for me.

Comment: its fix. i change security option in propertis page. it message me tha the file was creat but that file have nothing. just creat an empty text file

Answer (score 1):

The reason of `System.Security.SecurityException` in your call of `File.Create` method. It creates file and opens `FileStream` on created file. You did not close opened by `File.Create` stream so `StreamWriter` can not open a second one.

Change code to following:

```
const string path = @"d:\export.txt";
using(FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using(TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream)) {  
    int rowcount = dgvSum.Rows.Count;
    for(int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++) {
        sw.WriteLine(dgvSum.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(@"Text file was created.");
```

Comment: @HoomanDaddy close all text editors with opened `d:\export.txt` file or just try different file

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
try
{
    string filepath = @"d:\export.txt"
    using (TextWriter stream = File.Exists(filepath) ? new StreamWriter(filepath) : new StreamWriter(File.Create(filepath)))
    {
        int rowcount = dgvSum.Rows.Count;
        for(int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++) 
        {
            stream.WriteLine(dgvSum.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception) { }
```

Comment: As per my comment on the original post. Have you checked that you have permission to write to that location? Could you try somewhere else like the desktop?

Comment: i cheked all premissions .

Comment: Ok, I've wrapped the code in a try-catch block. Can you step through it and give a screenshot of the exception when it lands on it. Also, do you have the file open anywhere else when you're trying to run this code?

Answer (score 0):

1. right click on the file "export.txt" -> Properties -> Security make sure your user has write permission.
2. use streams inside using statement like

   ```
   using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
   {
        using (var textReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

add this in config file and I think this will work for you

Comment: <system.web>

<trust level="Full"/>

</system.web>