# File being used by another process

Tags: c#, file-io

I have this problem in C# that this code gets executed, and it
does not go through, it gives me an error "File being used by another process" (or similar).
I've tried looking for answers on Stack, but I couldn't quite put together all of it.
I attempted to insert some more code (like they said) there, but just hands me more errors.
Please help, many thanks in advance!

Below is my current code =>

```
// let's create example.py
string path = @"C:\example.py";
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileAccess.Read);
var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
if (!File.Exists(path)) {
    File.Create(path);
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
    tw.WriteLine("# code to insert into target file");
} else if (File.Exists(path)) {
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\example.py", string.Empty); // clear contents
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
    tw.WriteLine("# more code to insert into example.py");
}
```

This is my original code (no fix attempts) =>

```
// let's create example.py
string path = @"C:\example.py";
if (!File.Exists(path)) {
    File.Create(path);
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
    tw.WriteLine("# code to insert into target file");
} else if (File.Exists(path)) {
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\example.py", string.Empty); // clear contents
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
    tw.WriteLine("# more code to insert into example.py");
}
```

Comment: `File.Create(path)` returns a stream. It's what's locking the file. See my answer here for a possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676746/i-want-to-get-export-from-datagideview-to-text-file-but-i-get-folowing-error?noredirect=1#comment62886667_37676746

Comment: off topic but FileStream, StreamReader should be disposed manually.

Comment: wrap you objects around a `using( ){ }`

Answer (score 1):

I have found this works entirely ->

```
// let's create example.py
const string path = @"C:\example.py";
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{
    {
        sw.WriteLine("First line");
        sw.WriteLine("Second line");
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: More importantly...do you understand **why**?

Comment: This is actually what people have told you :) That `using Filestream` closes the filestream for you

Answer (score 0):

See: [File being used by another process after using File.Create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781357/file-being-used-by-another-process-after-using-file-create)

Just remove File.Create and directly use:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to close `FileStream` which is returned by `File.Create`:

```
  File.Create(path).Close();
```

see MDSN for details

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx

A better approach, however, is just to write into file:

```
  if (File.Exists(path))
    File.AppendAllText(path, "# more code to insert into example.py");
  else 
    File.AppendAllText(path, "# code to insert into target file");
```

Or even

```
File.AppendAllText(path, File.Exists(path) 
  ? "# more code to insert into example.py"
  : "# code to insert into target file");
```